# Create static route for WiFi connection

Tags: networking

My android 4.4.2 device is on a corporate network which requires a static route to access another subnet.  This static route is served by DHCP but I don't think Android is respecting it.

Is there a way to add a static route manually?  (For a wifi connection - not a VPn connection)?

As well is there a way to show the routing table in Android 4.4.2?

Comment: The subnet I need to reach is not accessible through the default gateway.  (Keep in mind this is a corporate environment with numerous subnets and routes).  I was able to print the routing table on my andoid device and confirmed that it ignore the routes send with the DHCP response

Comment: Does your phone have the `ip` utility?